# RecyclerView inside CardView issue with UI

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, cardview

I'm having an special case where I need to show a list of items inside a CardView (or a view that is very similar to an CardView).

The functionality works well, but I encountered some inconsistencies regarding the UI for this:

- On API bellow 21 the CardView is shown as empty (I guess this is due to how the CardView widget sets it's padding so that it can draw it's shadow - simulating the elevation) -> I overcome this by showing or hiding the entire view depending on the adapter status, if I have data or not
- The corners are not displayed correctly and the UI is not consistent on all API levels
- For remove actions on the RecyclerView items, the animation is a little weird. The height of the RecyclerView is resized first and after that the next rows are animated into the position of the row view which was removed.

Also, I cannot rely on the CardView content padding because I have dividers matching the width of the card view.

Did anyone encountered an similar situation and found an solution for this?

Thank you in advance for any help or tips on how to achieve this.

LE: I've added ScreenShots with how it looks like on API 22 and on API 16.

**API 16:**

[image: API 16]

**API 22:**

[image: API 22]

The CardView above the RecyclerView inside a CardView is a simple CardView with only a TextView as it's content. 
As you can see there is a difference between the simple CardView and there is also a difference between API levels.

**SOLUTION:**

I've identified the problem and fixed it in 2 steps:

- the wrong margins and corners it was due to some overdraw in row view
  layout. I've removed the background from the row view completely and
  left the background only on the RecyclerView's parent CardView
  holder.
- the empty CardView holder of the RecyclerView being shown when no data is available I've fixed by adding an data observer on the adapter of the RecyclerView and I always update the CardView holder visibility based on the number of items I need to display (when empty I completely hide the list with it's CardView holder).

Comment: Can you share how it is looking ?

Comment: I've updated my question and I've added ScreenShots.